# Escaping the Escape Character in Regex not working

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression

```
regex = '[\w!\-$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";\'<>?,.@#\\/]+'
```

When i try to match the regular expression with a string for example

```
password = '\Gs7iCHE'
```

no match is found but when i change the regular expression to

```
regex = '[\w!\-$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";\'<>?,.@#\\\\/]+'
```

it finds a match which is

```
match = '\\Gs7iCHE'
```

I dont know why the behavior is this way.

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: "In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-). The usual metacharacters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash."

Comment: If you're using PCRE, it looks like it doesn't like the last "/": https://regex101.com/r/rI0vW6/1

Comment: Is this javascript? In that case the backslash ``\`` needs to be escaped to have it in a string. And since the escaped ``\`` needs to be escaped in the character set, you have to enter ``\\\\``. In your first case it escapes the `/`.

Comment: Also, the other escapes just makes the javastring escape, thus you escape `w` and adds a range `!-$`.

Comment: My regex flavour is from python @ClasG the `\w` represents `[a-zA-Z0-9]`  and i did not use a range. from the regex, after `\w!`, i escaped the - to avoid it being a range. The only `\`   that should be considered is the last one before the  \`/\` because every other use is for escape reasons.

Comment: That's what I mean - check my answer. The ``\`` in python (and js... and ...) escapes the character in the string. To escape in the regex you have escape the escaped character ;)

Comment: In the first regex, i escaped the escaped character and it did not match the string.

Comment: That's because you escaped the ``\``  - `...@#\\/]+'` - making python see it internally as `...@#\/]+'`. Then when the regex parser gets it, it interprets the `/` as escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is correct. Use raw string `r` before regex and it will work fine

```
re.compile(r'[\w!\-$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";\'<>?,.@#\\/]+')
```

**[Check](https://regex101.com/r/jE6dO2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

The backslash `\` needs to be escaped to have it in a string. And since the escaped `\` needs to be escaped in the character set, you have to enter `\\\\`. In your first case it escapes the `/`

Also, the other escapes just makes the string escape, thus you escape wand adds a range `!-$`.

In other words - try:

```
regex = '[\\w!\\-$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[\\]:";\'<>?,.@#\\\\/]+'
```

No need to escape the `[`.

Regards

Comment: The regex is correct but it still returns double `\\` in the password string which was my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed your regex to the second one `\\\\`
parses into `\\` for single quote strings.

This is ok and all, but now your regex matches the literal escape.
And since its inside a quantified character class `[\\]+`, it's going
to match as many escapes as in your target string.

Your target string is `\\Gs7iCHE` and sure enough, it matches the entire thing.

One thing to note about escaping single quote strings,
This `'\\\'` is identical to `'\\\\'` after parsing. Namely, they both
become `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, I came across this kind of an issue once. In JavaScript (and many other languages) RegExp is delimited by slashes, followed by mode flags. 
If you want to use escaped characters, you have to include your regexp inside **//**.